# How can I set AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL programmatically in asp.net core web api project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am hitting a wall for not being able to set the AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL value to true programmatically. I have tried to set the value in AddAuthentication but could not get the property. I know its part of MicrosoftIdentityOptions.AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL but could not get it. below is the attempt by myself.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(a => { a.Audience = AUD; }, b => { b.ClientId = ClientId; b.Instance = Instance; b.TenantId = TenantId; });
```

Comment: Please try adding `options` within `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`

Comment: the b is the MicrosoftIdentityOptions but I cannot find AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL in it.

Answer (score 1):

Require me to update the Microsoft.Identity.Web to 2.16 version.